# Ethernet issue in TP720 - working fine for U16.04 while keeping breaking in U18.04, U20.04 and U20.10

Tags: networking, lenovo, ethernet

Hi every Ubuntu experts,
I really need your help to get the issue fixed. I had been trying to install Ubuntu for almost 2 days and tried different version - 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, 20.10.

My server: Lenovo Think Station P720
Network:

1. Intel Corporation I210
2. Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM

Problem: When I installed Ubuntu for U20.10, everything worked fine except the network. For the wireless, it could connect to the hot spot shared by my mobile while it couldn't connect to a normal router.
For ethernet, there were two connections while either of them looked not stable. It showed "Connected" for a few seconds and then showed as "Unplugged" soon. Even I could see the ip address was assigned. But, the network was not established.

Later, I tried to install U20.04, U18.04 and got similar issue.
Finally, I tried U16.04 while it worked well and the network issue was never shown up. But, U16.04 was too out of date.

I guess that it was probably caused by the driver issue and tried to install Intel driver. While no luck, the compile was failed.

Not sure if anyone met the similar issue and could you pls share how you resolved it? Really appreciate if you could help me!!!

```
root@BobTP720:~# lspci|grep net
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I219-LM (rev 09)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
----------
root@BobTP720:~# lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I219-LM (rev 09)
    DeviceName: i219
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection (3) I219-LM
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    DeviceName: i210
    Subsystem: Lenovo I210 Gigabit Network Connection
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
```

Comment: I tried to disable IPV6 while not worked as well.

Comment: Were you using the GA kernel on 16.04? or HWE kernel?   Which kernel were you using on 18.04?  (ie. were you using the same kernel & near stack on both 16.04 & 18.04? (namely 16.04 with HWE & 18.04 using GA) or different stacks?)

Comment: Hi Guiverc, thanks for your response! I am using the standard distribution - https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop. I didn't use any special edition.  I reinstalled with U20.10 and right now the Kernel version is 5.8.0-25-generic. I guess that for all other versions I was using the "generic".

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases come with two kernel stack choices, the GA or general kernel (ie. original kernel), which for 16.04 LTS was 4.4.  It's used by default with installs of 16.04 or 16.04.1 media; but later media (16.04.2 or later) defaults to HWE which results in the kernel upgrading before finally settling on the GA kernel of 18.04.  ie. I was asking which media you used to install your 16.04 system; thus which kernel option you selected to use (unless you changed it post-install). https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: If you were using the same hardware stack on both 16.04 you said worked, plus 18.04 you said didn't work.... that's a HUGE clue as to your problem, currently though you've not clarified which stack you used thus if they were the same, or different.   (the later releases will be different; your 18.04 & 20.04 maybe the same, again you weren't specific, and 20.10 will used the 20.04 HWE stack which isn't available yet by default so is currently different...)

Comment: Thanks Guiverc! I am not sure if I answered your question about the Kernel. I got to know to run "uname -r" to get the kernel version. Pls let me know if you want me to run other command.

Comment: Thanks Guiverc! I didn't change anything in the hardware. Just tried with different version of Ubuntu. U16.04 worked, U18.04, U20.04, U20.10 didn't work.

Comment: Was it 16.04, 16.04.1, 16.04.2 ... 16.04.7 you tried... ie which 16.04 release was installed & tried?  The kernel details (which show the stack used) of the 16.04 are what I'm asking, 5.8 used by 20.10 or 20.04.2 isn't what I'm asking, I'm asking about 16.04 that worked.

Comment: Sorry, Guiverc. I just erased 16.04 since I did want to install newer version. So, I am afraid that I couldn't provide the information now. I am trying to install the network adapter driver https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-?wapkw=I219 and hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ThinkStation P720 [is certified for Ubuntu 16.04](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201706-25568), which would explain why the network drivers exist for your machine there. That said, there is a solution.

1. Download the `e1000e-3.8.4.tar.gz` from [the Intel Download Centre](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-)
2. Untar the file with: `tar -xfv e1000e-3.8.4.tar.gz`
3. Go to the source directory: `cd src`
4. Compile and install the driver: `sudo make install`
5. Reboot

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Matigo! Yes, I am trying with this approach and will update here later.

Comment: unfortunately, I got above error. Maybe the kernel is too new and Intel is not ready to support U20.10 :-(

Answer (score 0):

After trying lots of different ways and finally got it fixed by,

1. disabled IPv6
2. Manually set ip address, gateway and dns server for IPv4
   reboot.